# Quickbooks online crud sample application with production keys is not working

Tags: production-environment, quickbooks-online

Quickbooks online crud sample application with production keys is not working. The authorization url has #RealmSelection at end of url. It opens popup for company selection but popup has no company listed on it. There is only cancel button.

The same sample application is working fine with development keys. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using production keys with trial account is not allowed.

Comment: Do you mean that the developer account requires a paid subscription to quickbooks online? Or the account you are connecting to can't be a trial account?